# Navigation based application with an add button

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, xib, ibaction

I created a new Navigation Based Application project.Then in MainWindow.xib I added a button to the navigationbar. I would like to push a new View onto the screen where I can enter information, which will be added as an object to the array of the UITableView.

But I don't know where to write the IBAction to link the button to (Appdelegate or the RootViewController)? Because as you see in the screenshot, it resides in MainWindow.xib because the RootViewController is merely a Table and doesn't contain the navigation. But in the document view of MainWindow.xib it is located under the RootViewController.

Do I have to create a new View Controller inside the XIB as well and create an IBOutlet for it?

I tried putting the code inside my AppDelegate and reference the button to the delegate but it doesn't work.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

See the screenshot here: http://i56.tinypic.com/5djbcm.png

Answer (score 1):

When you ask yourself a question "where does this action belong" it's most probably a controller because controllers handle event flows in your app. Next question - "What controller is in charge when this action happens? What controller is most interested in this action?". Answer in your case is root table controller (`RootViewController` instance). Create an `IBAction` method in it which will push form controller (one you use to enter information) to navigation controller.

```
// somewhere in RootViewController.m
- (IBAction)addNewEntry {
    NewEntryFormController *c = [[[NewEntryFormController alloc] init] autorelease];
    // ...

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:YES];
}
```